# Is there any way to host my local host Jenkins to a Public IP

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am a newbie learning jenkins. Currently learning the scenario of github webhooks integration to trigger a build upon every git events. I understand that the webhooks does not support private IP or LocalHost of jenkins. To Achieve this, we need a public IP.

I tried using ngrok and other similar which is a proxy that expose localhost to public URL. The problem here is, when i input the ngrok jenkins url to webhook it has more connections which the ngrok restricts and asking to have premium membership to achieve this.

I would be great is someone help in giving me a reference on how to host my local host to a free server so that i can have a public ip.

Comment: That's a networking question really, this pretty much depends if you can expose ports from your router and forward them to your machine. Probably a DDNS would need to be used if you don't have a static IP.

Comment: I do not know under what assumption you are setting up your local host to be exposed to public NW. If it is only for experimentation purpose, please get a trial account on any hyper-scaler like GCP or AWS. You can spin up a dockerized Jenkins on a VM and assign a public IP.

Comment: Yup thanks for the suggestion. Will try to work on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can! GitHub Webhook documentation explains it. Essentially, you'd use ngrok to ssh ur localhost into a unique ngrok publicly accessible link.

TLDR;
Take a look at [this](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/creating-webhooks#exposing-localhost-to-the-internet)